# flex 4.6 access an object ID when passed as a var to a function

Tags: apache-flex, variables, actionscript, mxml

flex 4.6

I am wondering how to access/change an object using a var passed to a function, for example if I have the id `vg1Text`, using

```
Application.application.vg1Text.text = txt2chg+":"+id2chg;
```

works but

```
Application.application.id2chg.text = txt2chg+":"+id2chg;
```

fails with

`ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property id2chg not found`

thx Art

module

```
public function chgFuncB1(txt2chg, id2chg):void {
    Application.application.id2chg.text = txt2chg+":"+id2chg;
    }
public function myFunc() : void{
   chgFuncB1("New Text", "vg1Text");
   }
```

Main Application

```
<s:VGroup id="vg1">
    <s:Label id="vg1Text" text="Module loaded in Spark VGroup container:"/>  
</s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, you can use the array notation (hope that's the correct name for it). In this way, the String contained in the variable `id2chg` can be used as a property name.

```
public function chgFuncB1(txt2chg:String, id2chg:String):void {
    Application.application[id2chg].text = txt2chg+":"+id2chg;
    }
```

Comment: Thx @Sunil I think the issue is when the code is run it is seeing id2chg as the object name not a var to be replaced or it would return NULL if it is a local var would it not?

Comment: That's correct, there's no variable replacement or substitution on the statement `Application.application.id2chg.text`. For that line to mean something, you need an object in your main app that that has the id "idc2chg" (or a variable declared in the script block of that name). Let me edit my answer, I just realized what you are trying to do...

Comment: Ok, that should work... I was a little dense and just got hung up on the error :)

Comment: not dense at all, many perspectives to the same problem, thx for the quick response. Art